# How to remove an object which is inside [nested] of an object which is in an object array [MongoDB]?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document:

```
{
    "Name": "Downhill 3",
    "Apartments": [
        {
            "Yardage": 55.5,
            "Owner": {
                "name" : "Timothy",
                "surname" : "Notclement",
                "phone" : 555666777
            }
        },
        {
            "Yardage": 70,
            "Owner": {
                "name" : "Anya",
                "surname" : "Joylor-Tay",
                "phone" : 555111000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It represents "all" apartments at some street.

I want to delete one entry from **Apartments** array, let's say the one which is owned by Anya, by specifying it by something like this `Apartments.Owner.name:"Anya"`.

How can I perform such an operation? I tried to `$pull` and to `$unset`, but nothing worked. Now I came across `findAndModify` ([docs here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.findAndModify)) and possibility to use an **aggregation pipeline** in the **update** field, but can't really figure out how to form a query.

*Mongo commands I tried*:

```
db.ApartCollection.update( { "_id":ObjectId("example123") }, { $unset: { "Apartments.Owner.name" : "Anya" } } )

db.ApartCollection.update( { "_id":ObjectId("example123") }, { $unset: { Apartments: { "Owner.name" : "Anya" } } } )

db.ApartCollection.update( { "_id":ObjectId("example123") }, { $pull: { Apartments: { "Owner.name" : "Anya" } } } )

db.Dokumenty.update( { "_id":ObjectId("61881be8dd6d25184a3b6c3f") }, { $pull: { "Apartments.Owner.name": "Anya" } } )
    ^This one doesn't even ?compile? It returns error:
    Cannot use the part (Owner) of (Apartments.Owner.name) to traverse the element ({Apartments:...blah blah
```

Comment: `$pull` with update is the correct usage; see the [example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#remove-items-from-an-array-of-documents) in the MongoDB Manual.

Comment: Thank you @prasad_, but I saw this example and the closest one to my is the one where it is showed how to remove an object which contains an array. Tried this, but it didn't work (because my case is different). Or maybe I am missing something? Can you maybe post a query which I can try?

Comment: `{ $pull: { Apartments: { "Owner.name": "Anya" }}}` - is the correct syntax. Maybe your query filter `{ "_id":ObjectId("example123") }` is not correct?

Comment: You are right... I've checked it now, and it works. Strange thing is, when I tried this before, it deleted the whole Apartments array... Probably did something wrong.
Should I delete this question or maybe you @prasad_ can answer and I will mark it as correct answer?